# Licence for Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, licensing, vba

I've worked with colleagues on an excel add-in we would like to sell to our customers. It is linked to a cloud database. A licensing system is currently coded in VBA, but that's pretty weak and potential hackers getting around the VBA protection would be able to disable the licence checking (code protection is not such a problem as such).

We have been thinking of developing a .dll file to check licences, but lack of expertise in the field.

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: VSTO is a good option. However have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984229/how-can-i-create-product-keys-for-vba-applications-so-that-illegal-distribution/13985132#13985132)

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, it looks good. A similar approach is currently in use, though less fancy than yours. The only drawback is that all code stays in VBA. I agree, we should go to VSTO to get something more secure. We'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Others can post about .NET licencing solutions....

From years back Microsoft Component Object Model (COM) does have a licence system.  One writes the code in C++ and clients use COM to instantiate your component.  The COM licence mechanism is to implement the `IClassFactory2` instead of `IClassFactory`   Here is a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680095(v=vs.85).aspx

Now you may say "but my code is in VBA!?".  Well, VBA is not secure, workbooks can be broken into.  The problem is that the source is shipped inside.

Compiling a .NET solution is better but the executable is Intermediate Language (IL) which can be reverse engineered back to the source.  Same problem with Java, 'byte code' can also be reverse engineered.

For the most robust code security you need to compile to C++.  Even with C++ some people say it can still be reverse engineered.

The ultimate in paranoia is to place your valued code behind a web service so it is never on the user's computer.

Comment: Thanks S Meaden. I hear you, but it won't be feasible to rewrite the full project in C++ at this stage. You are right, reverse engineering the project wouldn't be that difficult  but would currently cost much more than the licence fees: the code is obfuscated and nearly unreadable. Besides, our customers are small businesses usually with little knowledge of VBA, and hopefully not enough time and resources to dedicate to hacking. We tried to bypass VBA security problems by a relatively affordable price compared to the service given to customers.

Comment: The weakest point is that licence (related to Mother Board ID) is checked in the VBA code. I was hoping to find a stronger and better way to licence the add-in, even if security might always be an issue.

Comment: Tying to a piece of hardware is just fine.  Difficult to fake a mother board id; others use the Mac-Address of a Network Interface Code which apparently is also unique.

Comment: Yes, hopefully that will be a good enough deterrent. And I agree with your concept of paranoia. Web services solve this issue, but also have limitations when it comes to integration with other applications (excel for instance).