# Is there a way to set an expiry date on VBA module code or add-in code (.xlam)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have some code that I want to distribute for a 90 day trial period. I am able to set a dynamic expiry date based on the first instance that a user opens the Workbook. However, I am wanting to sell my code as an add-in and need a way to incorporate a similar function in my add-in Module code. I.e. if the user installs the add-in, is there a way that I can store the first date the code is run and terminate after 90 days no matter what workbook the add-in is run?

Here is the code for the Workbook:

```
Private Const NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION = 90 

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim PassWord As String

PassWord = InputBox("Please input password. Trial expires in " & NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION & " days.")

If PassWord = "123" Then

    Dim ExpDate As String

    On Error Resume Next

    ExpDate = Mid(ThisWorkbook.names("ExpDate").Value, 2)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Name doesn't exist
    'Calculate new expiration
    ExpDate = CStr(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + NUM_DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRATION))
 
    'Create a named range and store the date here
    ThisWorkbook.names.add name:="ExpDate", RefersTo:=Format(ExDate, "short date"), Visible:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
 
    If CDate(Now) > CDate(ExpDate) Then
        MsgBox "This workbook trial period has expired.", vbOKOnly 
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False 'this removes the entire vb code
    End If
    
    Else: MsgBox "Password is incorrect."
    Application.Quit

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How is the Add-In "visible" to the user? via a separate ribbon tab?

Comment: with a little modification, you can probably make this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984229/how-can-i-create-product-keys-for-vba-applications-so-that-illegal-distribution

Comment: If your customers aren't too tech-savvy, you could very easily store the date (or an encrypted equivalent) in the registry. See `GetSetting` and `SaveSetting` commands.

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot really do that for people with a medium level of VBA knowledge... Since the VBA project protection can be easily cracked, having access to the code they can see how it checks the respective date and adapt the code to skip that part. Only in a COM add-in things may stay differently...

Comment: @FaneDuru Indeed a COM add-in is a better solution, but it can still be decompiled. So any solution that involves a hard-coded password is doomed.

Comment: @Kostas K.  Of course! That's why I wrote "may stay differently". Meaning that much more effort in cracking is necessary...

Comment: I wrote a few Add-In's in my life and  made the mistake to put to much energy in safety.
Even writing com add-ins with vb6. 
You should put your energy in getting it into the world and don't think about the few crackers.
Instead do some stuff which the normal user will not look at. Make it for you as easy as possible.
You could also use ExcelDNA in .net to make it a little bit harder to decompile (a little bit)
But still - put your energy in selling it.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! @sous2817 I will have a look at trying to modify this code.

Comment: @CLR Thank you for the input. I doubt the customers will try and 'hack' the code. I will have a look at these commands.

Comment: @RedHare Thank you for the advice. We have put in a lot of effort to get to this point. Just need the user to have to input a new password after 90 days of first opening the add-in.

Comment: @Ike That will be the idea. We will give them the add-in file (.xlam) and a front-end excel sheet that uses the various functions in the add-in. So my concern is that if I create the 90 day password expiry code for 'ThisWorkbook' only, if the user opens another workbook then they can freely use the add-in. The code needs to be in the actual Module code itself.

Comment: If you have an add-in with the functions provided via ribbon you don't need a workbook. But what you can do is to not show the ribbon when password is wrong or trial is over. I second @RedHare: The intermediate user won't try to crack Excel - and the ones who want to will find a way.